# Use jasmine spyOn with function

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine

I need to write unit test cases in jasmine (& karma) for something like below. It uses `rollup` to compile it.

```
const A = () => {
 B();
}

const B = ()=> {
 console.log("B is called");
}

exports {A}
```

In here my `test.js` file, I need to check whether the B() is called, when we call A(). So I try something like this.

```
import * as mainFunctions from 'main.js'

describe("" , function() {
  beforeEach(()=> {
    spyOn(mainFunctions, 'B');
    A();
  });

  it("", function() {
    expect(mainFunctions.B).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But it gives me the error "Error:  : B is not declared writable or has no setter" when I run the test. Please suggest me a method to overcome this.

Answer (score 1):

`B` is *private* for all intents and purposes (it's not exported) and you should **not** directly test *private* methods.

What you can test is the effect of `A`. We `expect` that when `A` is called `console.log` will trigger. So you can test the effect by spying on `console.log`.

`console.log` in this case is a module dependency. When writing Unit-Test you should mock (spy) on all used dependencies and call all the available public methods.

```
spyOn(console, 'log');

...

it('should print log to console', function(){
  mainFunctions.A();
  expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

> Note: `console` should **not** be used directly (or mocked) in production. You should implement a `LoggerService` (see: [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)) and spy on it instead.

Comment: So, is it impossible to check whether the B is called or not?

Comment: Impossible. You can't directly test `private` methods only their effects.